# same user appears many times in people

Tags: jira

When a colleague searchs under "People" tab in JIRA, the same user appears many times.
But when I login as admin an go to "User management > Users" I only see this user once.

Do you know any method to avoid this?

Thanks,

PS: We're paying the 10 users license, it'll be a terrible surprise to be charged more for a mistake on my side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently encountered this problem.

If you are using OnDemand, contacting support seems to be the only option.

If you are hosted, find details here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Duplicates+in+the+People+Directory

Comment: great! they are going to use the solution (the link) you provided :-)

Comment: Solved :)
As a word of warning, a downtime for maintenance was needed, so it's better to schedule when you want this to be solved.